# Find the intersection coordinate of a line and a 3D surface defined by a contour plot

Tags: regions, geometry, computational-geometry, intersection

I have two points, for instance `{1, 1, 1}` and `{10, 11, 15}` that connected to form a line. I also have an enclosed surface region got by a contour plot. How can I find the coordinate of the intersection of the line and the surface?
I tried the function `RegionIntersection` but it doesn't work I guess because the two regions have different embedded dimensions. And even if it works I don't know how to extract the coordinate.

Could somebody help me with this?

[image]

The code to get the region is like:

```
    Iso = ListContourPlot3D[DataTable, Contours -> 
          {0.5}, ContourStyle -> {Yellow, Opacity[0.7]}, DataRange -> 
          {{x0,x1}, {y0,y1}, {z0,z1}}, Mesh -> None, BoxRatios -> {x1- 
          x0, y1-y0, z1-z0}];

    RegionSurface = RegionBoundary[BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[Iso]];

    RegionIntersection[RegionSurface, Region[Line[{{0, 0, 0}, {10, 11, 
    19}}]]]
```

where the `DataTable` is a 3D table containing volumetric data read in from a file. One example of the `RegionSurface` is given by the following picture:

[image]

Comment: Solve[ x^2 - y^2 - z == 
   0 && (1 - t)*{1, 1, 1} + t*{10, 11, 15} == {x, y, z} ]

Comment: The hard part is that I don't have an expression for the enclosed surface region. It is got by a contour plot of a 3D volumetric data and applying "RegionBoundary[BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[ ]] "

Comment: You need to post your code about the region.

Comment: This is an example from the [http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionIntersection.html] page in the section Scope > Special Regions. The solution is: `Line[{{-(3/Sqrt[14]), -3 Sqrt[2/7], -(9/Sqrt[14])}, {3/Sqrt[14], 
   3 Sqrt[2/7], 9/Sqrt[14]}}]`. Have a look there.

Comment: Oops, sorry, this link seems to lead me to an empty page. And for the code I got the region is just that I use ListContourPlot3D to find a enclosing contour and use RegionBoundary[BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[ ]] to get the region of its surface.

Comment: @Dennis Please, can you post the code in the body of the question by editing your question? What you’ve noted does not make it easier to help answer your question. Kindly, post the code in a markdown formatted way, of what you use your `ListContourPlot3D` on, and then the subsequent code to get to where you are now stuck. The goal, essentially, is to make it so future users who have the same question as you can come along, copy and paste your code, and any answers that are given, and solve their problems as well. As it stands, this remains difficult to answer, lacking the code that is needed.

Comment: @CA Trevillian Sorry, my fault, just got into Mathematica Stack Exchange and haven't been familiar with how to properly post questions... And I added my code in the description which should be clear now :)